# MySQL json_remove returns null

Tags: mysql, json, parsing

I have a table called **product_option_param** that has a column **povs** of JSON type, which basically keeps JSON arrays with ids (for example, `[1,2,3]`)

When I need to delete, for example, an id **1**, I execute this:

```
UPDATE product_option_param 
SET povs = JSON_REMOVE(
   povs, replace(JSON_SEARCH(povs, 'one', 1), '"', '')
) 
WHERE json_search(povs, 'one', 1) IS NOT NULL
```

But it just turns all cells that have **1** in the array into null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SET @`id` := '1';

UPDATE `product_option_param`
SET `povs` =
  JSON_REMOVE(
    `povs`,
    JSON_UNQUOTE(
      JSON_SEARCH(
        REPLACE(
          REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
              `povs`,
              '[',
              '["'
            ),
            ']',
            '"]'
          ),
          ',',
          '","'
        ),
      'one',
      @`id`
    )
  )
)
WHERE
  JSON_CONTAINS(`povs`,  @`id`);
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cTbtQdzLn9uwshENqoxBns/0).